# Android App Iframe a site

Tags: java, android, iframe

I was trying to make android app for my radio station. I want when user will open the app the site will load automatically. I was following this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)
but when I tried to run the app it's showing this error "Unfortunately,Tarab Radio stop work "
Here is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView 
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

& MainActivity.java

```
  package com.jibon.tarabradio;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview;
        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("http://hoicoimasti.com/radio/");

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Any Idea where I did mistake. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); in your onCreate method.

Comment: Thanks.. I realized the problem after submit here ... Anyway thanks for you ans :). But do you have idea how I can add a loading animation upto load the site ?

Comment: Add ProgressDialog and show before load webview, set WebViewClient on your webview and dismiss progress dialog in WebViewClient's onPageFinished method.

Comment: Can you give me the live code ? I am new in app development. But thanks for hints :)

Comment: I opened another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20302949/progress-status-in-android-app-with-iframe-a-site